# More control over Facebook "like"

Tags: javascript, facebook

I need to be able to allow a user to "like" something on my website, but I need control over the content that shows up in the wall post. How do I do this?

"Like" only allows me to specify a URL to "like".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. After clicking the "like" button the user will be prompted for an optional comment.